# how to get all nodes with a specific name, by using the match attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get a set of nodes in an XML file, by using the match attribute the following way -

```
<xsl:template match="//title" name="split">
```

and it doesn't seem to work.

this is the XML file I am trying to work with (taken from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c.xsl"?>

<bookstore>
    <book>
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

this is the xsl file I am trying to run

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="//title" name="split">
    <xsl:value-of select=".">
    </xsl:value-of>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the desired output is : Harry Potter Learning XML

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Please explain in detail what "doesn't seem to work" means.

Comment: all the content was included, not just the node I wanted as @Johnson meant in his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a template matching the title correctly, but you don't have anything catching and ignoring everything else, so all the text content is going to be included.

Throw in a match-all template which just re-applies the stylesheet on everything else. Note if you do it this way you don't need the wildcard `//title` match and can just match on the element name.

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="title" name="split">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Harry Potter Learning XML
```

Comment: good answer, but how to handle additional space at the end of the output?

Comment: You can actually replace the second template with just `<xsl:template match="text()" />` as XSLT's [built-in templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) will handle the rest. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGd7

Answer (score 1):

use this. added space in between the concatenated values, feel free to modify

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="concatvalues" match="bookstore">
        <xsl:variable name="concatenatedValue">
            <xsl:for-each select="book/title">
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(./text(), ' ')"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$concatenatedValue"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: your answer works but Johnson's answer was more what I was looking for. thanks!